# Android imageView1 start animate and after 1000ms start imageView2

Tags: android

i write this code to my image animate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backImage);
        ImageView img2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.upImage);
        animBounce=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.bounce);
        animBounce.setAnimationListener(this);

        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        img.setAnimation(animBounce);

        img2.setAnimation(animBounce);

    }
```

i have a two imageView,imageView1 name in xml file backImage And imageView2 name in xml file upImage.
i want img start animate and after 1000ms img2 start animate but in this my code img and img2 At the same time start.
How can o solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backImage);
    ImageView img2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.upImage);
    animBounce=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.bounce);
    animBounce.setAnimationListener(this);

    img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    img.setAnimation(animBounce);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            img2.setAnimation(animBounce); 
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Add it to end of `onCreate` method. I hope it helps.

Comment: yes i test it now,but two image animate same in time.